# How to group every 2nd and 3rd items of an array into sub-arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects

`const objects = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g ... ]`

and I want them to turn into

`const result = [a, [b, c], d, [e, f], g ... ]`

Any ideas?

[Edit] My apologies. This is my first post, didn't know I have to show my attempts. I don't think I deserve the mean comments either, be nice people. I solved it after a head-banging 4 hours. Here is my solution:

```
const result = []
     const method = array => {
         for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 3) {
             const set = new Set([array[i + 1], array[i + 2]])
             if (i !== array.length - 1) {
                 result.push(array[i])
                 result.push(Array.from(set))
             } else {
                 result.push(array[i])
             }
         }
     }
```

Thanks for the responses guys! I read every single one of them.

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: "Please do my homework"

Comment: A quick google will answer this. Literally the first 5 results are showing many different options.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a while loop and push either an item or a pair of items.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    grouped = [],
    i = 0;

while (i < array.length) {
    grouped.push(array[i++]);
    if (i >= array.length) break;
    grouped.push(array.slice(i, i += 2));
}

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plain `for` loop and `%` modulo operator.

```js
const objects = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
const result = []

for(let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  if(i % 3 === 0) {
    const arr = objects.slice(i + 1, i + 3)
    result.push(objects[i])
    if(arr.length) result.push(arr)
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```js
const objects = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
let result = [];
let toGroup = false;
for(let i = 0; i < objects.length ; i++){
    if(toGroup){
        result.push([objects[i], objects[++i]]);
    }
    else result.push(objects[i]);
    toGroup = !toGroup;
}
```

this has a particular case that you have not specified, where it doesn't work, for example if inside `objects` there are 2 elements, and so i don't know what you would like to do in that case